# How do you replace the words that are only appearing once with other word within a text file using Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I am having trouble with replacing the words that are only appeared once within a text file.

Let's say I have a text file containing:

I have a pen,
I have an apple,
Uhhh! Applepen,
I have a pen,
I have pineapple,
Uhh! Pineapplepen.

The result I expect to get is

I have a pen, I have an apple, Uhhh! (unique), I have a pen, I have pineapple, Uhh! (unique).

Here is my example code in Python:

```
new_unique_word_file = open('new_unique_word.txt' , 'w' , encoding='utf-8')
with open('new_train.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as unique_word_file:
    line = unique_word_file.readlines()
    counts = dict()
    for each_line in line:
        each_line.split()
        for word in each_line:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1
                for each_word in counts:
                    count_word = counts[each_word]
                    if count_word == 1:
                        modified_line = each_line.replace(each_word ,'(unique)')
                        new_unique_word_file.write(modified_line)
```

What I got as result is very strange and I really can't find a proper way to do it.
Appreciate the help!

Update, I just found out that I made a mistake. The output file should be
I have a pen, I have (unique) apple, (unique) (unique), I have a pen, I have pineapple, (unique) (unique).

Comment: Why is pineapple not replaced into (unique)? "Uhhh!" "Uhh!" as well?

Comment: Not exactly know what's the expected result.

Comment: From the original text file, the pineapplepen and applepen should be distinct and unique from any other words by comparing all of them. So when looking through the entire file, we can see these two unique words, then I want to replace them with '(unique)'. My bad, I should include 'Uhhh!', 'Uhh!', and 'an' as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `regex` to find all words minus punctuation/spaces. Then just use `string.count()` to check the number of occurrences per word.

However your example does not match your expected output as there are more unique words then you specify.

```
import re
string = "I have a pen, I have an apple, Uhhh! Applepen, I have a pen, I have pineapple, Uhh! Pineapplepen."

for word in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]\w*', string):
    if string.count(word) == 1:
        print(f"Unique word found: {word}")
        string = string.replace(word, '(unique)')
```

Output:

```
Unique word found: an
Unique word found: Uhhh
Unique word found: Applepen
Unique word found: pineapple
Unique word found: Uhh
Unique word found: Pineapplepen
>>> string
'I have a pen, I have (unique) apple, (unique)! (unique), I have a pen, I have (unique), (unique)! (unique).'
```

You can apply the same logic over your entire text file, or line by line.